# Is $\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)^{o} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^{o}$?

Tags: general-topology

$A^{o}$ is the set of all interior points. The definition of an interior point is as follows: Let $A$ be a set of real numbers. A point $p\in A$ is an interior point if and only if $p$ belongs to some open interval $S_p$ which is contained in $A$.

Claim: $\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)^{o} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^{o}$

proof: Let $A_i = (-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i})$ Then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}) = (-1,1)$. So, $$\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)^{o} = (-1,1)$$ $A_i^{o} = (-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i})$ then $\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^{o} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{i},\frac{1}{i}) = (-1,1)$ Therefore, $$\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i\right)^{o} = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^{o}$$

I am not sure if this is right, and I feel like I could use a similar argument to prove that it does not equal, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why when you union intervals together you get $\{0\}$ (first line of the proof)

Comment: The union of your $A_i$ is $(-1, 1)$. Maybe you're thinking of intersection.

Also not sure why you can let $A_i$ be defined that way, it wasn't an assumption in the question.

Comment: Made the changes thank you, was thinking of intersections... long day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $A_j\subseteq\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ and consequently $A_j^o\subseteq(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)^0$ for each $j$ so that $$\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i^o\subseteq(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i)^0$$

The opposite inclusion is not true in general.

---

Counterexample:

If $F=[0,1]$ and $G=[1,2]$ then $F^o\cup G^o=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ and $(F\cup G)^o=(0,2)$. So the sets are not the same.